# String increment of characters for a column

Tags: python, string, pandas

I've tried researching but din't get any leads so posting a question,

I have a df and I want the string column values to be incremented based on their ascii values of each character of string by 3

```
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

   Name  Age
0   Tom   10
1  Nick   15
2  Juli   14
```

Final answer should be like Name is incremented by 3 ASCII numbers

```
    Name  Age
0   Wrp    10
1   Qlfn   15
2   Myol   14
```

This action has to be carried out on a df with 32,000 row. Please suggest me on how to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using python's built-in `chr` and `ord` (it seems like you want an increment of 3 not 2):

```
df['Name'] = [''.join(chr(ord(s)+3) for s in i) for i in df.Name]
```

---

```
print(df)

   Name  Age
0   Wrp   10
1  Qlfn   15
2  Mxol   14
```

Comment: After df.Name - > if i is not None @Toros

Comment: Why `if df.Name`? Use `[''.join(chr(ord(s)+3) for s in i) for i in df.Name if i is not None]` @Toros

Comment: With which new values?  @toros

Comment: Lets continue [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207405/room-for-yatu-and-toros91) @toros

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below,

```
data = [['Tom', 10], ['Nick', 15], ['Juli', 14]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

def fn(inp_str):
    return ''.join([chr(ord(i) + 3) for i in inp_str])

df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(fn)
df
```

Output is

```
    Name    Age
0   Wrp     10
1   Qlfn    15
2   Mxol    14
```

Comment: only suggestion is to avoid using lambda just to assign it, at that point you might as well use a normal `def` syntax.